# Install alpine package from alpinelinux.org

Tags: alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I would like to install *mozjs91-dev* package on my alpine machine.
When I try to install it via apk, I get an error that it wasn't found:

```
user@demo:~$ sudo apk add mozjs91-dev
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  mozjs91-dev (no such package):
    required by: world[mozjs91-dev]
```

I found the package in alpinelinux.org: [link](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/mozjs91-dev).
I tried to install it by defining alpinelinux.org as a repository, but still not found:

```
user@demo:~$ sudo apk add mozjs91-dev --repository="https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/mozjs91-dev"
fetch https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/mozjs91-dev/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/mozjs91-dev: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/mozjs91-dev: No such file or directory
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  mozjs91-dev (no such package):
    required by: world[mozjs91-dev]
```

What is the proper way to download and install this package?